# How to drop mongodb in docker container from npm script

Tags: mongodb, docker, npm

I'm running a mongodb (v.4.0.9) in a docker container for testing purposes. I want to be able to run a npm script to drop the database to be able to restore other backups to the database.

Regarding the mongodb [tutorial](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/) for doing things like that in the terminal it's possible but without any success on my side. The db container exposes the port 27016.

`"drop: mongo localhost:27016/databaseToDrop --eval db.dropDatabase()"`

Actually the database should be dropped, like documented [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.dropDatabase/).

No error message or something like that is appearing, neither the db gets dropped.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `getSiblingDB` to be able to run commands on another db with `--eval`. The following npm script worked for me:

```
{
  "name": "docker-npm-mongo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "docker-start": "docker start some-mongo || docker run --name some-mongo -d mongo:latest",
    "docker-create-db": "docker exec some-mongo mongo --eval db.getSiblingDB('mydb').user.insert({'name':'test'})",
    "docker-drop-db": "docker exec some-mongo mongo --eval db.getSiblingDB('mydb').dropDatabase();"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Use these npm commands to create the database

```
npm run docker-start
npm run docker-create-db
```

Then you can check whenever your DB exists by doing

```
docker exec -ti some-mongo mongo
> show dbs
```

After you're done you can drop db by executing

```
npm run docker-drop-db
```

You have to delete the docker container manually with this command. As an alternative, this can be also part of your npm script as a separate command.

```
docker rm -f some-mongo
```

Comment: Hi Oresztesz, thanks for your answer, the getSiblingDB was the point. Just for completness i used the mongo cli which then looks something like... `"drop: mongo localhost:27016 --eval db.getSiblingDB('databaseToDrop').dropDatabase()"`.